# How to change element select option with onClick and onChange using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to change the style of arrow on select option. The default style is caret-down. So, if cursor click the input area then change the style with caret-up. And if the select option has changed or it didnt do anything then back to default style.

**This is my html :**

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div id="select" class="col arrow-down">
      <select name="idBengkel" class="form-control custom-select" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Item</option>
        <?php foreach($bengkel as $row):?>
          <option value="<?= $row['idBengkel'];?>"><?= $row['nmBengkel'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**This is my css :**

```
.custom-select{
  position:relative !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.arrow-down::after{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f0d7';
  position: absolute;
  right:10%;
  bottom: 15%;
  font-size: 120%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow-up::after{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f0d8';
  position: absolute;
  right:10%;
  bottom: 15%;
  font-size: 120%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**This is my js :**

```
<script>
  $('#select').on('click', function () {
    // Button clicked
    $("#select").removeClass("arrow-down");
    $("#select").addClass("arrow-up"); 
  });
  $("select").change(function () {
    // Option selected
    $("#select").addClass("arrow-down");
  });
</script>
```

Regard!

Comment: Post generated html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm removing a `addClass()` changed with `toggleClass()`, then using a `hasClass` into second `on('click')`.
 So I changed also css into `arrow icon` to `border` tag.

**jQuery**

```
$('.custom-selectbox select[name=idBengkel]').on('click', function( e ) {
$(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
return false;
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
var $arrow = $('.custom-selectbox');
if ($arrow.hasClass('open')) {
    $arrow.removeClass('open');
} else {
    return false;
}
});
```

**CSS**

```
 select { /* For Example */
    color: #000;
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
 }

 .custom-selectbox{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 .custom-selectbox:after{
  content: '';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 8px;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.custom-selectbox.open:after{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="form-group row">
   <div id="select" class="col custom-selectbox">
    <select name="idBengkel" class="form-control custom-select" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Item</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Example**

```js
$('.custom-selectbox select[name=idBengkel]').on('click', function( e ) {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
   return false;
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var $arrow = $('.custom-selectbox');
    if ($arrow.hasClass('open')) {
        $arrow.removeClass('open');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

```css
select { /* For Example */
    color: #000;
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.custom-selectbox{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.custom-selectbox:after{
  content: '';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 8px;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.custom-selectbox.open:after{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.arrow-down::after{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f0d7';
  position: absolute;
  right:10%;
  bottom: 15%;
  font-size: 120%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow-up::after{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f0d8';
  position: absolute;
  right:10%;
  bottom: 15%;
  font-size: 120%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group row">
  <div id="select" class="col custom-selectbox">
    <select name="idBengkel" class="form-control custom-select" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Item</option>

      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```